# Is it possible to login to wordpress from cPanel?

Tags: cpanel

Is it possible to login to wordpress from cPanel? If then how please answer this.
I search here and there but not find a clear answer of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot log into your Wordpress Dashboard from CPanel. You can only do this from the Login url. Typically www.domain.com/wp-login.php .

However you can access the database and change records/tables if you desire.